# Dynamically setting a DataTable's RowFilter

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I've got a DataTable with up to 20K rows being built during run time and then thrown into a DevExpress GridControl. I've added two filtering options that were initially being checked when the query was run... Meaning that if you wanted to change an option, you had to re-query and rebuild this massive DataTable and then remove the unwanted rows. This, obviously, was pretty inefficient and time consuming. I decided to make try to make this a little nicer by not making it rebuild the DataTable but simply filter it.

Initially, I came up with this god-awful looking chunk of code:

```
if (!cheBinObjFolders.Checked)
{
   dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "File NOT LIKE '*bin*'";
   dt.DefaultView.RowFilter += " AND File NOT LIKE '*obj*'";
   isFiltered = true;
}
else
{
   if (!isFiltered)
   {
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "File <> ''";
      isFiltered = true;
   }

   else
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter += " AND File <> ''";
}

if (cheNormalFiles.Checked)
{
   if (!isFiltered)
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Status <> ''";
   else
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter += " AND Status <> ''";
}

else
{
   if (!isFiltered)
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Status NOT LIKE '*Normal*'";
   else
      dt.DefaultView.RowFilter += " AND Status NOT LIKE '*Normal*'";
}
```

So I wanted to improve it, make it cleaner and easier if and when more filtering options get added. So I set the Tag property on my checkboxes to be the Column name ("File" or "Status") the checkbox would filter and wrote this:

```
//Empty quotes should be the actual right-hand side of the expression
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is CheckEdit)
   {
      if (((CheckEdit)c).Checked && isFiltered)
         dt.DefaultView.RowFilter += c.Tag.ToString() + "";
      else if (((CheckEdit)c).Checked)
      {
         dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = c.Tag.ToString() + "";
         isFiltered = true;
      }
      else
         dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = c.Tag.ToString() + "<> ";
   }
}
```

However, I have no idea how to dynamically come up with the right hand side of the expression like this. Any ideas what I could do? I'm kind of thinking I should just subclass this Checkbox control and add 2 string properties; "Field" and "Filter" then just use those to build my filter. Is there a better way?

**Edit:** Alright, I came up with this with your suggestions/advice:

```
    private string BuildTableFilter()
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckEdit && control.Tag != null)
            {
                var c = (CheckEdit)control;

                if (c.Checked)
                {
                    if (!filters.Contains(c.Tag.ToString()))
                        filters.Add(c.Tag.ToString());
                }
                else
                    filters.Remove(c.Tag.ToString());
            }
        }

        return String.Join(" AND ", filters.ToArray());
    }
```

So all I need to do in the future is just add the proper Filter expression to the Tag. Unfortunately, with so many rows it still locks up the UI briefly (5 seconds maybe), so I'll need to tackle that next...

Comment: You might want to build the filter by adding to a list of separate statements, then do a string.Join, using " AND " as the join string.

Comment: Looks like you have some checkBoxes not only 2?

Comment: @KingKing There are only two right now, but in the future it's possible there could be more. The first, hardcoded segment of code has 1 IF / ELSE for "cheNormalFiles" and 1 IF / ELSE for "checkBinObjFolders"

Comment: Why don't you modify the GridView's ColumnFilter for the `File` and `Status` columns instead of the DataTable filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to build the query using a list of statements (in this case, the Tag would be the filter statement for that control);

```
 var filterTerms = new List<string>();

 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
 {
     if (c is CheckEdit)
     {
        if (((CheckEdit)c).Checked)
        {
             filterTerms.Add(c.Tag.ToString());
        }
     }
 }

 dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", filterTerms);
```

Comment: This is just an idea, normally should work but may not be applied in the OP's case easily because I can feel that he doesn't implement something really called `filtering`, looks like each `CheckBox` has 2 associated expressions, one for `Checked = true` and one for `Checked = false`

Comment: Trying a blend of this, subclassing like I said in my original post, and Rachel's comment suggestion of just applying the filter to the GridControl... why I didn't think to check if the Grid had a filter property is beyond me. Looping through the controls, adding a filter to a List based on some new properties on the control, and then throwing that Joined string into the GridControl.

Comment: Marking this as the Solution since I was able to derive something successful out of it, thanks a ton.